# Retrieve all messages in Slack(more than 1000)

Tags: slack-api, slack

I want to retrieve all the messages that were sent in my teams slack domain,more than year.

i'm using  `channels.history method` to retrieve the history of each channel,

But this method returns maximum of 1000 records only.

`count  100 Optional, default=100`
`Number of messages to return, between 1 and 1000.`

And i dont have access for  https://my.slack.com/services/export to export all the data.

Also timesatmp is not way to get the desired data, beacuse my slack channel recived more than 1000 message per day

Are there any possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get all messages with [`channels.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history) for your situation. Here is how:

1. Call the method once to get the newest 1000 messages (1st chunk)
2. Call the method again with `latest` property set to the timestamp of
   the oldest message you received in the last chunk and the
   `inclusive` property set to `false`. This will get you the next
   chunk of 1000 messages
3. Repeat until you received all messages

Remember that the rate limit is 1 call per second, so make sure you don't call the API more often.